# Warning: Text content did not match in React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, jsx

recently the project I am working on has been upgraded to React 18. By then, suddenly a lot of issues with hydration have started to appear as warnings/errors in the console. The one I'm struggling with is "Warning: Text content did not match":

[image]

Code of this component:

```
 <div className="O75-product-faq__questions is-active accordion--initialized">
                            {
                                dataForSelect.length > 1 && <h4 className="O75-product-faq__questions__name js-category-name">{props.questionsByCategories[selectedCategory?.value].name}</h4>
                            }
                            {
                                props.questionsByCategories[selectedCategory?.value].questions.map((element, i) => (
                                    <div key={i} className="O75-product-faq__questions__item">
                                        {(element.question || props.showOnlyAnswer) && <div className={`O75-product-faq__questions__item__button${openedElement === i ? ' has-accordion-open' : ''}`} onClick={() => openElement(i)}>{element.question}</div>}
                                        <AnimateHeight height={openedElement === i ? 'auto' : 0} duration={transitionDisabled ? 0 : 400}>
                                            <div className="O75-product-faq__questions__item__content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: element.answer }} />
                                        </AnimateHeight>
                                    </div>))
                            }
                        </div>
```

I know that this issue results from the difference between client and server side rendering, but I don't know how to fix it and  no other similar question contained solution that worked in my case.

Rest of the file, in case if the issue is not with aforementioned part:

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import type { ReactElement } from 'react';
import AnimateHeight from 'react-animate-height';
import { BaseSelect, SelectOption } from '../molecules/base-select';
import type { FrequentlyAskedCategory } from './frequentlyAskedQuestion';
import { fromBase64 } from '../shared-services/base64Service';

interface FaqPanelProps {
    mainTitle?: string;
    menuTitle?: string;
    showOnlyAnswer: boolean;
    currentPageUrl: string;
    questionsByCategories: Record<string, FrequentlyAskedCategory>,
    faqStructuredDataBase64: string;
}

const FAQPanel = (props: FaqPanelProps): ReactElement => {
    const categories = Object.keys(props.questionsByCategories);
    const dataForSelect: Array<SelectOption> = categories.map(key => ({ label: props.questionsByCategories[key].name, value: key }));
    const noOpenedElementIndex = -1;

    const [openedElement, setOpenedElement] = useState<number>(-1);
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState<SelectOption>(dataForSelect.length > 0 ? dataForSelect[0] : null);
    const [transitionDisabled, setTransitionDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const parsedStructuredData = useMemo(() => {
        if(props.faqStructuredDataBase64 != null && props.faqStructuredDataBase64 !== ""){
           return fromBase64(props.faqStructuredDataBase64);
        }

        return "";
    }, [props.faqStructuredDataBase64]);

    const selectNewCategory = (option: SelectOption): void => {
        setTransitionDisabled(true);
        setOpenedElement(noOpenedElementIndex);
        setSelectedCategory(option);
    }

    const openElement = (index: number): void => {
        if (transitionDisabled) {
            setTransitionDisabled(false);
        }
        setOpenedElement(index === openedElement ? noOpenedElementIndex : index);
    }

    const speakableJson = JSON.stringify({
        "@context": "https://schema.org/",
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "name": props.mainTitle,
        "speakable":
            [".O75-product-faq__headline",
                ".O75-product-faq__questions__item"],
        "url": props.currentPageUrl
    });

    const hasFAQStructuredData = parsedStructuredData != null && parsedStructuredData !== "";
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <section className="O75-product-faq" >
                {
                    props.mainTitle
                        ? <h2 className="O75-product-faq__headline">{props.mainTitle}</h2>
                        : <h4 className="O75-product-faq__categories-headline">{props.menuTitle}</h4>
                }
                <div className="flex">
                    {dataForSelect.length > 1 &&
                        <div className="O75-product-faq__categories">
                            <div className="filter__list is-hidden-sm filter">
                                {
                                    dataForSelect.map((element, i) => (
                                        <button className={`filter__btn js-filter__btn${element.value === selectedCategory?.value ? " is-active" : ""}`} key={i} onClick={() => selectNewCategory(element)}>
                                            {element.label}
                                        </button>))
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div className="filter__group is-hidden-md">
                                <BaseSelect selectedValue={selectedCategory}
                                    handleChange={selectNewCategory}
                                    options={dataForSelect} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    {categories.length > 0 &&
                        <div  className="O75-product-faq__questions is-active accordion--initialized">
                            {
                                dataForSelect.length > 1 && <h4 className="O75-product-faq__questions__name js-category-name">{props.questionsByCategories[selectedCategory?.value].name}</h4>
                            }
                            {
                                props.questionsByCategories[selectedCategory?.value].questions.map((element, i) => (
                                    <div key={i} className="O75-product-faq__questions__item">
                                        {(element.question || props.showOnlyAnswer) && <div className={`O75-product-faq__questions__item__button${openedElement === i ? ' has-accordion-open' : ''}`} onClick={() => openElement(i)}>{element.question}</div>}
                                        <AnimateHeight height={openedElement === i ? 'auto' : 0} duration={transitionDisabled ? 0 : 400}>
                                            <div className="O75-product-faq__questions__item__content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: element.answer }} />
                                        </AnimateHeight>
                                    </div>))
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                {hasFAQStructuredData && <script suppressHydrationWarning type="application/ld+json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:parsedStructuredData } }></script>}
                <script suppressHydrationWarning type="application/ld+json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: speakableJson}} ></script>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

export { FAQPanel };
export type { FaqPanelProps }
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?